# Resize an image resource in CQ5

Tags: thumbnails, aem

I am trying to resize a given JCR image resource and store it as a new rendition. The use case is to generate thumbnails in "any" scale.

I wanted to use the `com.day.cq.dam.core.process.CreateThumbnailProcess`, but this it is not available in the project, i am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a quite low level approach, to resize an image identified by `jcrPathToImage` to `int targetWidth` and `int targetHeight`.

1. Resize Image

   ```
   Resource resource = getResourceResolver().getResource(jcrPathToImage);
   Asset asset = resource.adaptTo(Asset.class);
   Layer layer = new Layer(asset.getOriginal().getStream())
   layer.resize(targetWidth, targetHeight);
   ```
2. Create new rendition in JCR

   Extract mime type of the original image

   ```
   Image image = new Image(resource);
   String mimeType = image.getMimeType();
   ```

   Store the resized Image using its asset representation.

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream bout = null;
   ByteArrayInputStream bin = null;

   try {
       bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
       layer.write(mimeType, 1, bout);

       bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bout.toByteArray());

       asset.addRendition(resizedImgName, bin, mimeType);

   } finally {
       // close streams ...               
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you can configure the DAM  Update Asset workflow to give the renditions you want to get created

```
http://localhost:4502/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html
```

in this workflow model select the thumbnail creation step and in the process tab of that step you can add your custom thumbnail values

[140:100],[48:48],[319:319],[90,90]